# Estimote beacon enter and exit monitoring

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, beacon, estimote

I need event for user enter in range and exit from range.To get Enter and exit notification in android device I have Used beaconManager.setMonitoringListener from Latest sdk:1.0.2 but I am getting repeatedly Enter and exit event, If my phone is near to beacon still getting exit event.I need technical solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is the main objective of the beacons, check again manufacturer tutorial.